# Storing Values in keychain

Tags: ios, security, keychain

I am creating two different object of keychain for some purpose

```
KeychainItemWrapper *wrapper = [[KeychainItemWrapper alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"ACommonIdentifier" accessGroup:@"Agroup"];

KeychainItemWrapper *wrapper_app = [[KeychainItemWrapper alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"randomeId" accessGroup:nil];
```

And storing some values in both keychain . Values are being stored in both keychain.

## EDIT

```
[wrapper setObject:@"SOME_VALUE" forKey:(id)kSecAttrService];
[wrapper setObject:@"SOME_VALUE" forKey:(id)kSecValueData];
 

[wrapper_app setObject:@"SOME_VALUE" forKey:(id)kSecAttrService];
[wrapper_app setObject:@"SOME_VALUE" forKey:(id)kSecValueData];
```

Problem is that when I am retrieving the value from both object,

either there is no value in 'Wrapper'  or no value in 'Wrapper_app'.
Means every time one of the keychain is having no value.

Please suggest and help me..
thankss

Comment: Where's the code for `KeychainItemWrapper`?